# Upgrade from v3 to v4 Unable to get user info from provider

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I followed the next-auth guide to upgrade from v3 to v4, but I am not getting the user info with our custom provider.

Here is my provider config:

```
Auth0Provider({
    id: providerId,
    name: providerName,
    type: 'oauth',
    version: '2.0',
    
    scope: ['openid', 'email', 'profile', 'member'],
    grantType: 'authorization_code',
   
    issuer: `https://${auth0Domain}`,
    
    profile: (_profile) => {
      logger.info('Login profile found for:' + _profile.name + ':' + _profile.sub);
      logger.debug('Login profile details:' + JSON.stringify(_profile));
      return {
        id: _profile.sub,
        name: _profile.name,
        email: _profile.email,
        everything: JSON.stringify(_profile),
      };
    },
    clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
  })
```

The return `profile` object has some data, but not the user information.
A similar config in v3 is returning the needed user information.
Did I miss something?
Can you help me with that?
Thanks